# Make a POST request with microsoft translator

Tags: azure, authentication, post, postman, microsoft-translator

I'm trying to use my Microsoft Translator API and I'm having trouble.

[image]

I'm adding the corresponding headers and a body.

[image]

I extracted my keys from here
[image]

But I'm getting this response

[image]

Does anyone know where this mistake might come from?

Comment: What happens when you include the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region` header by ticking its box?

Comment: Same thing, I've tried that on and off, but it shouldn't be necessary for this POST.